# How to bind a related object property to a TextBlock in DataGridTemplateColumn with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have two objects Exercise and Objective, each Exercise has one Objective.
In the code behind I set the ItemsSource of the Exercises DataGrid

```
 dgExercicios.ItemsSource = Repositorio<Exercicio>.GetAll();
```

And in my XAML.

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgExercicios" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
             <!--This bind works (Exercice.Nome)-->
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nome" Binding="{Binding Nome}" Width="200"   />
             <!--This bind DONT works (I Trying to bind to Exercise.Objective.Descricao)-->                     
             <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Objetivo"  Width="80" >
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate  >
                             <StackPanel>
                                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Objective.Descricao}" T />
                              </StackPanel>
                          </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
```

What I want to do is to bind the property Exercise.Objective.Descricao to the TextBlock on the Exercice.Nome

Another question, will a DataGridTemplateColumn be needed in this case?

Comment: In visual studio debug mode, when your program is running, the 'output' window should contain error messages for binding errors. Can you post what it says?

Comment: @Hi Stephen Hewlett. I had never thought to look in the output window, if fact, it help me a lot, i ended up discovering that may problem was (in fact) the loading of related entities in EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it will work if the Exercise class has a property called Objective, and the Objective class has a property called Descricao.

```
public class Exercicio
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Objective Objective { get; set; }

    public Exercicio(string nome, Objective objective)
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
        this.Objective = objective;
    }
}

public class Objective
{
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public Objective(string d)
    {
        this.Descricao = d;
    }
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var items = new ObservableCollection<Exercicio>(new[] {
        new Exercicio("Exercicio1", new Objective("Objective1")),
        new Exercicio("Exercicio2", new Objective("Objective2")),
        new Exercicio("Exercicio3", new Objective("Objective3"))
    });

    dgExercicios.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

And you don't need a DataGridTemplateColumn if you just want to show a string:

```
<!-- Works now (also in a normal text column) -->
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Objective.Descricao}" Header="Objetivo" Width="80" />
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, your answer solves my problem. In fact, in a first moment it not works, but i ended up facing that my problem is the Loading of related entites with EF, so i will mark it as answer, thanks again.